# Erro ao executar uma função em JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando executar esta função:

```
function createSlick(){  

    $(".slider").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        autoplay: true,
        dots: true,

        slidesToShow: 4,
        responsive: [{ 
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                dots: false,
                arrows: false,
                infinite: false,
                slidesToShow: 1,
                slidesToScroll: 1
            } 
        }]
    }); 
}

createSlick();
```

Mas está dando este erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).not(...).slick is not a function

Alguém poderia me ajudar a resolver?

Comment: Provavelmente a biblioteca do plugin não foi carregada.

Comment: Você importou o jquery?

Comment: Estou chamando aqui:

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/produtos.js"></script>